# Unexpected network error, please try again later. Amazon Sales Channel

Tags: magento2, api, sales, amazon

I am using `Magento 2.3.6` and have installed `Amazon Sales Channel 4.4.0`, I have added the `Production API Key`   and `Production Private Key` under `Magento Services` but I get this error "`Unexpected network error`", can anyone explain what causes this error?

[image]

Click Add Amazon Store and I get this error:

[image]

**Browser Console:**
GRAPHQL ERROR:
Error: GraphQL error: Internal server error
https://cdn.amazon.channels.magento.com/4.4.0/static/js/components/HelperFunctions/GQLErrorHandler.tsx

```
import { ApolloError } from 'apollo-client';

interface MagentoNetworkError {
  name: string;
  response: {};
  statusCode: number;
  result: {
    ajaxExpired: number;
    ajaxRedirect: string;
  };
}

/* 
 If Magento is open in 2+ tabs, and the user signs out in one of them, all
 the other sessions will also be terminated. All GQL queries & mutations will
 return a Network Error that follow the pattern in the interface above. 
 
 If that's the case, display a toast
 that will not go way. If it's any other error, then just display whatever 
 custom message was passed in. 
 */

export const GQLErrorHandler = (error: ApolloError | undefined, message?: string) => {
  let networkError = (error?.networkError as unknown) as MagentoNetworkError;

  if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {
    console.error(error);
  }

  if (
    networkError &&
    networkError.result &&
    networkError.result.ajaxExpired &&
    networkError.result.ajaxRedirect
  ) {
    errorToast(`Your session has timed out.`, {
      actionLabel: 'Sign in',
      onAction: () => {
        window.location.replace(networkError.result.ajaxRedirect);
      },
      timeout: 0,
    });
  } else if (error) {
    let errorMessage = message ?? 'Unexpected network error, please try again later.';
    errorToast(errorMessage);
  }
  console.error('GRAPHQL ERROR: \n ' + error);
};
```

Comment: Did you got any soulution

Comment: Iam using the Magento Commerce but for me i can't see magento services options

Comment: Getting exact same error in Magento open source version 2.4.1 and installed version of Amazon please channel is 4.4.1. Can anyone have any solution for this?

Comment: same... Magento 2.4.6. Module_Amazon is 4.5.0